# My site, its getting clipped

Tags: css, wrapper, viewport

i've made this website, it has a viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

it is still being partially viewed or clipped i guess if i try to view it through a CRT monitor at 800x600 desktop resolution or anything less than 1280x800, even mobile, can i make the site not clip or atleast make it horizontally scrolable but not clipped like it is right now? I guess the issue is with its wrapper, Any solution?

the site : http://techarx.com/

I hope i am safe with this.

Comment: THe issue is the width on #page. Change it to max-width, and then try realigning stuff

Comment: **Please don'd do this `maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;` it's very poor UX and is not recommended.**

Comment: @Paulie_D what do you recommend?

Comment: You can still use the meta tag just it's not recommneded to use those particular properties. We don't all have perfect vision and sometimes people need to be able to zoom/scale in.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the css. You currently have:

```
.page-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
}
#page {
    width: 1100px;
}
```

So when 80% of the window is less than 1100px things get cut off.

The quickest way to fix this would be:

```
.page-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 1100px;
}
#page {
    width: 1100px;
}
```

You could also make your #page div narrower, or make it width: 100%, but then you also need to adjust the inner columns.

Comment: I added min-width:1100px; no change, but when i did max-width: 1100px, it did make the page-wrapper narrower and everything out of their place, making seperate margin and min-width's for them all, thanks.